# MPDF bleedMargin / nonPrintMargin not working

Tags: php, printing, margin, mpdf

I'm using the MPDF library to generate some documents, and I'm trying to make the blank margins bigger.

I found two options in the doc: `nonPrintMargin` and `bleedMargin`.

I tried to change the values in both `config.php` and at runtime but I got no change.

Am I doing something wrong, or my printer overrides these settings ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you changed the overall width container?  Even if you set the margins, if the margin width is predefined via css, it probably won't allow a margin change on the document.

Comment: I tried to change width, height, sheet-size... of "@page"... no results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by making the sheet size a bit smaller than A4 :

```
sheet-size: 189mm 276mm;
```

Then when I print I **must** set in the printer options : 
Size : Real size (and not ADJUST or something).